# Smooth Div Scroll Left Hot Spot is Showing Cursor, but not scrolling and Right is Overly Fast

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, smooth-scrolling

So, I've implemented Thomas Kahn's Smooth Div Scroll into a Wordpress theme, and than am using a Zenfolio plugin to display scrolling images from Zenfolio galleries. The Zenfolio plugin seems to be working fine, but the Smooth Div Scroll seems to not be working correctly. It's auto-scrolling fine, but the left hotspot shows up, but doesn't respond, the right hotspot makes the scroll go way too fast. You can check the code, but I have the settings really slow, it shouldn't be moving quite that fast.

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="feature-slideshow">
<div id="makeMeScrollable">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s11/v27/p1106836720-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s1/v55/p1106836968-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s2/v58/p1106833686-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s1/v55/p1106834346-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s4/v62/p1106834158-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s2/v61/p1106834196-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <img src="http://wiltonphotography.zenfolio.com/img/s2/v58/p1106834786-4.jpg?sn="  class="portfolio-img">
    <!-- /zfp_photoset -->
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#makeMeScrollable { width:100%; height: 630px; position: relative; }
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img { display: none; position: relative; float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0 50px 0 0; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img:first-child { padding-left: 340px; }

/* Invisible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft { min-width: 50px; width: 10%; height: 100%; background-image: url(img/big_transparent.gif); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: center center; position: absolute; z-index: 200; left: 0; cursor: url(img/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.png), url(img/cursors/cursor_arrow_left.cur),w-resize; }

/* Visible left hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotLeftVisible { background-image: url(img/arrow_left.gif); background-color: #fff; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 0.35; -moz-opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity = 35); zoom: 1; }

/* Invisible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRight { min-width: 50px; width: 10%; height: 100%; background-image: url(img/big_transparent.gif); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: center center; position: absolute; z-index: 200; right: 0; cursor: url(img/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.png), url(img/cursors/cursor_arrow_right.cur),e-resize; }

/* Visible right hotspot */
div.scrollingHotSpotRightVisible { background-image: url(img/arrow_right.gif); background-color: #fff; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 0.35; -moz-opacity: 0.35; filter: alpha(opacity = 35); zoom: 1; }

div.scrollWrapper { position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
div.scrollableArea { position: relative; width: auto; height: 100%; }
```

JS:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // None of the options are set
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: true,
            hotSpotScrollingStep: 5,
            visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "",
            autoScrollingMode: "onstart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see the problem here: traviswilton.com

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the Smooth Div Scroll jQuery was interacting poorly with the Google CSS3 Media Queries JS I was using as well. I tried changing the cascading order, but it didn't seem to work. For this site, the CSS3 Media Queries JS wasn't necessary, so I just stripped it out and it Smooth Div Scroll works fine.

It's not a massive problem, but it would be nice if either Smooth Div Scroll or CSS3 Media Queries addressed it.